# Constructing sets including points included only in certain infinite number of sets from a given sequence of sets $E_n$

Tags: measure-theory

Consider we have a set $E_n$ for every natural number. The $E_n$ are sigma algebra elements. In order to complete a proof I want to construct a countable number of disjoint sigma algebra elements $F_m$, such that

$$\bigcup^nE_n=\bigcup^mF_m$$

In order to do this first I consider two types of points in $\bigcup^nE_n$ 1)those that are only in a finite number of $E_n$, for example, only in $E_1$, or only in $E_2$ *and* $E_3$ and so on; 2)those that are only in an infinite number of them, for example those points that are only in all the sets $E_n$ with even $n$.

I suceeded with category 1). Nonetheless with those of category 2) I haven't suceeded yet. Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Suppose $(E_n)$ is a countable family of sets in a $\sigma$-algebra $\mathcal{A}$. Since the family is countable, we may as well assume that it's indexed by the natural numbers.
Let $F_1=E_1$, clearly $F_1 \in \mathcal{A}$. We proceed by induction to define the $F_n$'s for $n\geq 2$. Whenever $F_n$ is defined, we define $F_{n+1} = E_{n+1}\setminus \left(\bigcup_{i=1}^n E_i\right)$. Note that for each $n$, we have: $F_n \subset E_n$ and $F_n$ is a member of $\mathcal{A}$, since a $\sigma$-algebra is closed under relative complements and finite unions. Therefore $\bigcup_n F_n \subset \bigcup_n E_n$.

Suppose $x \in \bigcup_n E_n$, then let $m= min\{n\ |\ x \in E_n\}$. Then, $x \notin \bigcup_{i=1}^{m-1} E_i$, otherwise it would contradict the minimality of $m$. Since $x \in E_m$, it follows that $x \in F_m$. Therefore $\bigcup_n F_n \subset \bigcup_n E_n$ and $\bigcup_n F_n = \bigcup_n E_n$ follows.

The only thing that remain is to show that the members of the family $(F_n)$ are pairwise disjoint. So, to that end, let $m\not=n$, w.l.o.g we may assume that $n < m$. Suppose that there is an $y \in F_m \cap F_n$. By definition of $F_m$, we have $y \in E_{m}$ and $y \notin E_k$ for any $1 \leq k < m$. But, since $y \in F_n$ and $n < m$, we obtain $y \in E_n$ and $y \notin E_n$, a contradiction. Therefore the members are disjoint.

Comment: Second paragraph I think you mean "since $x\in{}E_m$ it follows that $x\in{}F_m$. Otherwise superb

Comment: Yes, thank you, I'll edit.

Comment: Second paragraph I think youmeant $\bigcup_nF_n\supset\cup_nE_n$

Comment: Sorry, another typo.